# Which http method for updating single property

Tags: rest, api

I want to design an http route that sets a phone number as main for the current authenticated user.

could you suggest the proper http method and route to use.

I'm hesitating between **GET /auth/phones/{phone_id}/main** And **PATCH /auth/phones/{phone_id}** with object {main: true} in body request.

when setting a new main phone old main phone will automatically unset.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming `/auth/phones/{phone_id}` represents a particular phone number of the authenticated user, I would do the following:

```
PATCH /auth/phones/{phone_id}
Content-Type: application/json

{
    "main":true
}
```

HTTP method `GET` should not be used to modifiy resource state.

Comment: ya, it seems that PATCH is the more proper method. But here I don't understand why to hit the route /auth instead of auth/phones/{phone_id}. In may case a user could have a collection of phones, each phone with multiple properties (id, user_id, number, main, type(pro, perso), active, ...)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand that while I read your question. See my edit.

Answer (score 2):

According to Mozilla Foundation, PATCH is the correct way to apply partials updates to a record.

Read more in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/PATCH

Answer (score 1):

Typically, you don't want to modify data via a GET method.  The options you should be considering are POST/PUT/PATCH.  A typical approach would be:

- POST : creating a new entity, or sub-entity
- PUT : replacing an existing entity with the value(s) provided in the request
- PATCH : partially updating an existing entity